# LMC Program (Using branch) to store values in different locations

Tags: little-man-computer

So this is for a school project: I need to design a program (using a branch loop) that stores 1 in memory location 91, 2 in 92 etc... to 5 is stored in 95. I am not very knowledgable of LMC and would like some advice on it. I use peterhigginson.co.uk/LMC for my code (if that helps). The program cannot be as simple as store 1 in 91, it has to be done using a finite loop. I can easily ace this in any other coding console, just not LMC. Any help mucho appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not such an easy question. For code that writes to different addresses, you have to construct the correct `STA` instructions, using the encoding that `STA xx` is `3xx`.

Here's one way of doing it:

```
L LDA COUNT
  ADD INS
  STA X
  LDA COUNT
X HLT
  LDA COUNT
  ADD ONE
  STA COUNT
  LDA FIVE
  SUB COUNT
  BRP L
  HLT

COUNT DAT 1
ONE   DAT 1
FIVE  DAT 5
INS   STA 90
```

There's a counter (stored in `COUNT`) that goes from 1 to 5, and each time through the loop `L`, it's added to `390` (which is stored at `INS`) -- this constructs the instructions `STA 91`, `STA 92`, .., `STA 95` on iterations 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. This instruction is written at `X`, and then executed with `A` having the value of `COUNT`. The rest is just incrementing `COUNT`, and stopping when it gets larger than 5.

[Here's a live link, which you can see this code running on my own LMC emulator.](https://blog.paulhankin.net/lmc/lmc.html?program=TCBMREEgQ09VTlQKICBBREQgSU5TCiAgU1RBIFgKICBMREEgQ09VTlQKWCBITFQKICBMREEgQ09VTlQKICBBREQgT05FCiAgU1RBIENPVU5UCiAgTERBIEZJVkUKICBTVUIgQ09VTlQKICBCUlAgTAogIEhMVAoKCgpDT1VOVCBEQVQgMQpPTkUgREFUIDEKRklWRSBEQVQgNQpJTlMgU1RBIDkw&input=)